# type name does not allow storage class to be specified

Tags: objective-c, extern

```
@interface Foo : NSObject

{
    extern int gGlobalVar;   
    int i;
}
-(void)setgGlobalVar:(int)val;

@end


@implementation Foo

-(void)setgGlobalVar:(int)val
{  
    i = 5;
    NSLog(@"i = %i", i);
    gGlobalVar = val;
}

@end
```

I can declare `i` in interface and use it in implementation without any errors. But I cannot declare a variable of the type `extern` in interface. Why is this so? Why do I get an error which says that: "Type name does not allow storage class to be specified"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Short Description:**
The bracketed section of a class's `@interface` OR `@implementation` is only for *declaring* instance variables (aka "ivar").  The `extern` keyword is only for use with global variable declarations (or functions, but that's another topic.)
Therefore, you cannot declare an extern ivar.

**Gritty Details:** 
Variables are first declared, and then defined. This distinction is typically blurred for variables in local scopes, as a locally declared variable without an explicit definition will often be allocated and given a default value by the compiler.

Global variables are potentially available in any scope, provided that scope knows the global exists.  That's where the keyword `extern` comes in -- it *declares* that the global variable exists, and was *defined* elsewhere.  This is only useful when you want to access a global variable in different code files.

**Best Practices:** Your book has some code that declares an `extern` variable in an implementation file (e.g. ".m" files, etc.)... that can work, but it's a bad practice because you're making potentially bad assumptions about whether that global actually has a valid definition elsewhere.  (But, fancy compilers will discover this type of error.)

Instead, the best practice is to declare an extern variable once in a header file, have an accompanying implementation file that's dedicated to defining the externs in that header, and then include that header in other implementation files that want to use that global variable.

Comment: Thanks for your response HachiEthan. Coincidentally, the book that I am referring to, has used `extern` in '.m'  file.

Comment: @Rut Doing a little research, as I've not dug into the nitty-gritty of extern before! (And it will help me with my current work.) Will update answer soon. =)

Comment: Really appreciate it HachiEthan!